# Error updating in nHibernate: "Index was out of range."

Tags: nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate

When calling an update in FNH, I get the following error:

Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection.\r\nParameter name: index

It's probably some bad mapping.  What is the best way to diagnose this?  I really want to see the UPDATE it is trying to issue.

Here is the code:

```
    public void Update<T>(IEnumerable<T> values)
    {
            foreach (var value in values)
            {
                using (var tx = Session.BeginTransaction())
                {
                    this.Update(value, tx);
                    tx.Commit();
                }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 7):

If you could post your mappings it would help, but typically this occurs when you have mapped a Parent > Child relationship using the Fluent `References` syntax **AND** also included a Mapping for the Foreign Key column for the same relationship.

This results in nHibernate mapping the field twice and results in the error that you are experiencing.

When you use the References syntax nHibernate takes care of the Foreign Key column for you, however if you still want it in your object just change your mapping definition for that field to have the `ReadOnly()` option to cure the problem. If you don't need it you can remove from your mapping definition entirely.

To strictly answer the question asked (to diagnose yourself) I would suggest 2 options:

- Free option - install `log4Net` and configure nHibernate to output all of its SQL statements to the logger component. This way you will see the offending statement in the log files and be able to isolate the problem.
- Cost option - download and trial/purchase [nHibernate Profiler](http://www.hibernatingrhinos.com/products/nhprof) by Hibernating Rhinos. It will give you the full details of all SQL statements sent to the database by nHibernate, complete with recommendations or warnings for improvements, and all in a nice GUI.

Comment: This is exactly what it was - we had a reference and the foreign key both mapped.  nHProfiler did not help, as the error occured before and SQL was issued.  Now I know what to look for, though, I can get this next time.

Comment: Good, I am glad you sorted the problem